# Keras input data format

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, keras

I am trying to pass my own data structure to an LSTM layer in Keras, but the training of the model fails early on.

It is my intention to create a sequence of fixed length and to receive an output sequence of the same size. Currently, the sequence is as follows:

```
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
```

This is a list, which I then turn into an np array using np.array(). The label sequence is built similarly. In total, I have 8000 of such sequences, all of which have length 12.

In my Keras model, the LSTM is the first layer. This requires me to then pass the input shape of my data along to the model. I have tried filling in several shapes, but to no avail. For completeness, these are the first two lines of my model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(100, input_shape=(8000, 12)))
model.add(Dense(nb_classes))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
```

During training I ran into some trouble and I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42140922/keras-lstm-training-data-format) post. It seems very similar to what I am trying to do. I have tried the solution offered, but somehow the fitting still crashes. I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_1_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (8000, 12)
```

Any ideas?

UPDATE:
For Parthosarathi Mukherjee I added the rest of the network.

Answer (score 1):

```
model.add(LSTM(100, input_shape(8000, 12)))
```

instead use

```
model.add(LSTM(100, input_shape(12,1)))
```

make sure that before **fit** your input data has shape **8000 x 12 x 1** and not **8000 x 12**

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! If I do this I still get an error: 

ValueError: Error when checking target: expected activation_1 to have shape (None, 1) but got array with shape (96000, 2)

Comment: Please post some more code where you created the network. I am not sure from where the `activation_1` coming.

Comment: I have added the rest of the model.

Comment: It appears to me that your network expects a single value at each timestep so you should prepare your input array as 8000 x 12 x1. The label sequence should be also the same. Perhaps you made it 96000 x 2. If you want an output sequence of same size then the last layer should be `TimeDistributed(Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))`. Also your LSTM layer must have a parameter saying `return_sequences=True`. This does not appear to be a classification problem so you do not need a `softmax`